# How do I heat and/or build multiple snake enclosures?

Tags: reptiles, snakes, cage, enclosure

I am starting to get setup for snake breeding (balls) and I am lost on the process of multi enclosures. It is hard to find information about getting started with them and best practices/equipment to use because most links on google are just people selling them.

I am going to need at least 8 enclosures for the baby snakes and I was wondering if people build their own racks or if they just buy them online? If you build your own do you need a separate thermostat for each or just one thermostat hooked to all the (tape I assume) if it is a multi rack thing. Also should I get heating on all the enclosures or just the back or sides of the rack? Is there a problem with light using the racks?

Comment: If no one has an answer to this one I have done a lot more research and can do it this weekend

Answer (score -1):

You can buy snake racks online or you can get them made to order.

You will need a heat mat for each of the enclosures and depending on the snake depends on how big a draw.

Here are some links:

- [preloved.co.uk/(...)](https://www.preloved.co.uk/classifieds/pets/reptiles/all/uk/reptile+racks)
- [reptilesrevolution.com/(...)](https://reptilesrevolution.com/products/v-70-reptile-racks)
- [tgrracksystems.com/(...)](https://tgrracksystems.com/)
- [customcages.com/(...)](https://www.customcages.com/vision-snake-racks.html)

Comment: please do not post link only answers,links die and the answer becomes useless.

Comment: Isabelles Zoo, welcome. Please edit your answer to include relevant information from those sites. As it stands this link-only response does not really answer the question and will likely be deleted.

Comment: Sorry.its just easier to add links than to copy and paste 5 pages worth of stuff